# Migrate RDS Postgresql snapshot (v9.6 - encrypted) to aurora Postgressql compatible

Tags: postgresql, amazon-aurora

I am using RDS Postgresql v9.6 (can upgrade to higher version if needed) - encrypted enabled and I want to create a snapshot then migrate that snapshot to aurora Postgressql compatible (any version).
The issue is the "Migrate snapshot" is disabled. Any way to migrate a snapshot to Aurora? I read the AWS document but not found any help in this case - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraPostgreSQL.Migrating.html#AuroraPostgreSQL.Migrating.RDSPostgreSQL.Import.Console

[image]

Appriciate any help!